# Dynamically scaffold a JavaScript Object based on a string path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recursion, xpath

I'm attempting to dynamically build a JavaScript object from a string path recursively. The end goal is to have an object that is dynamically generated on some event.

Here's what I have so far, but I can't figure out why it's not working:
jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lo7uart/

HTML

```
<input type="text" data-path="/foo/bar/ni">
<input type="text" data-path="/foo/bar/ni">
<input type="text" data-path="/foo/bar/san">
...
```

JavaScript

```js
var storage = {};
var fields = $('.fields');

fields.find('input').each(function() {
    var field = $(this);
    field.change(function(event) {
        var currentField = $(this),
            currentFieldPath = currentField.attr('data-path').split('/').slice(1),
            currentFieldValue = currentField.val();

        function bindData(path, val, store) {
            if (store) {
                if (store.hasOwnProperty(path[0])) {
                    if (path.length === 1) {
                        store[path[0]] = val;
                    } else {
                        path.shift();
                        bindData(path, val, store[path[0]]);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (path.length === 1) {
                        store[path[0]] = val;
                    } else {
                        store[path[0]] = {};
                        var annex = path.shift();
                        bindData(path, val, store[annex]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        bindData(currentFieldPath, currentFieldValue, storage);

    });
});
...
```

Ideally, this should result in something like;

```js
{
    foo: {
        bar: {
            ni: 'some value, that'
            s been over written by the second input ',
            san: 'some value here'
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

The recursion works the first time around, but not ever after, haha. Any thoughts?

Comment: make a jsFiddle demo

Comment: @Legends Just added a jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lo7uart/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using the wrong object path (store[path[0]) in your code (line 18 of the jsfiddle.

Use this:

```
} else {
        var ann = path.shift();
        //console.log('path', store, path[0], ann, //store[path[0]], store[ann][path[0]])
        console.log('path', path, val)
        bindData(path, val, store[[ann]]);
}
```

instead of :

```
} else {
    path.shift();
    bindData(path, val, store[path[0]]);
}
```

Your path is an array of ['foo', 'bar', 'blablah'], so shifting removes 'foo' from the array. But you are trying to store your inputs at store['foo']['bar'], so doing store[path[0]] is trying to access an object at store['bar'] which doesn't exist.

Here is a working version

```
https://jsfiddle.net/j87m4z71/
```

Comment: Totally worked! I know I was missing something! Simple mistakes are illusive! Thanks dude! I own you a vegan lunch!